# Explicitly exclude an html element from the tab order

Tags: html, forms, tabindex

Is there any way to exclude an element from the tab order of a HTML form.

So if i have the following

```
<input type=text name=username>
<input type=text name=password>
<input type=button name=forgotpassword>
<input type=submit name=login>
```

I'm aware that I can use tabindex as 1,2,3,4 but i don't want to have to number all the fields. My application is dynamically creating the fields.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Setting the `tabindex` to **-1** will render an element untabbable (if that's a word) :)

```
<input type="text" name="username" tabindex="-1" />
```

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what i wanted.

Comment: And there went your accessibility, right out the door. Is it really that hard to set `tabindex="4"` for the  'forgot password' button, and `tabindex`es 1-3 for the rest?

Comment: @Lambart Note that MDN explicitly discourages using a tabIndex other than -1 or 0, i.e. you should restructure your DOM rather than providing explicit tabIndex order. Moreover, tabIndex -1 is considered by MDN to be **actually useful** for accessibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex