# How to catch the "Next" and "Prev" buttons in android and iOS when using PhoneGap / Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, cordova

How to catch the event when a user pushes the "Next" or "Prev" button when using PhoneGap and JavaScript / jQuery ?

I found several related questions, but the solution is in native code:

[how to catch 'next' button on soft keyboard of Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689932/how-to-catch-next-button-on-soft-keyboard-of-android)

[Android Soft keyboard action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007204/android-soft-keyboard-action-button)

[image]

Comment: Why? Maybe, there is another solution. There buttons are for navigationg between input-elements.

Comment: Because when I am at the login screen of my application, and push the "Next" button in the password text field, it takes the user to a different screen. I would like to prevent this

Comment: Are these buttons for navigation between pages and not for navigating between input elements? Did this change? Thought this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895710/explicitly-exclude-an-html-element-from-the-tab-order

Comment: I believe they are for navigation between input elements, but it changes page when one is at the last input element. I tried that tabindex solution, it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a way to disable the keys perhaps?

Comment: I'm writing a general solution (plugin) for this at the moment. The key idea is to have input fields indexed and to compare between them onblur/onfocus how the focused element is related to the blurred one.

Answer (score 0):

It will work automatically when it get 2 consecutive text-box

```
  </div> 
   <ul data-role="listview"  id="singup-form" class="tab"  >
   <li>
    <input type="email" name="text-6" id="email-id" value="" placeholder="Email Address">
    </li>
   <li>
   <input type="password" name="text-6" id="password-id" value="" placeholder="Password">   
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Click [here](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/textinputs/)! this will help you..